# Explanation of `cv.findHomography`

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, homography

I am trying to find the homography between two sets of points using opencv. I have source `src` and destination `dst` and I am computing the homography `H` a follows.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

src = np.array([[-47.59, -57.43, 139.59, 149.43, 46.],
       [141.43, 31.03, -1.43, 108.97, 70.],
       [579.23, 412.75, 422.55, 589.03, 500.89]])


dst = np.array([[-100, -100, 100, 100, 0],
       [-100, 100, 100, -100, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


H, _ = cv2.findHomography(src.T, dst.T)

print(np.allclose(H@src, dst))
```

OpenCV is computing the homography but when I try recovering the original `dst` using the computed `H`, it doesn't work. `np.allclose(H@src, dst)` gives `False`

However, if I take a closer look at the two arrays, the following is what I have.

[image: The top is H@src and bottom is dst]

There is a clear correspondence between the two sets of values. I would be almost be comfortable saying that they are just off by a scaling factor if it wasn't for the last row. Clearly a scaling factor of zero doesn't make sense. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, a 3x3 homography matrix computes the transformation between sets of 2D points between two spaces, having 0 in the last components of `dst` would be an issue.
This is because `src` and `dst` must be a set of 2D points in homogeneous representation. Hence, having 0 would make these points at infinity.

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```js
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = np.array([[-47.59, -57.43, 139.59, 149.43, 46.],
                    [141.43, 31.03, -1.43, 108.97, 70.],
                    [579.23, 412.75, 422.55, 589.03, 500.89]])

    dst = np.array([[-100, -100, 100, 100, 0],
                    [-100, 100, 100, -100, 0],
                    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])  # converting to homogeneous coordinates

    H, _ = cv2.findHomography(src.T, dst.T)
    dst_est = H @ src
    print(np.allclose(dst_est / (dst_est[2, :]), dst / dst[2, :], atol=1e-2))  # dividing by last component to fix the scaling and adjusting the tolerance
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that I am trying to find the homography between 2 sets of 3D points here, actually. I did try converting it to homogeneous coordinates by appending a row of ones to both the arrays, but then cv complains that 4D input in invalid. So does that mean that opencv homography cannot be used with 3D points at all?

Comment: If a 4D input in invalid, and the function always expects a homogeneous representation of the coordinate system, then I guess 3D points are invalid for the function? :(